# Change the Url when user copies

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Let suppose the user has enter

```
http://mysite/xyz.aspx .
```

. When he copies the URL from address bar I want to change it to 
`http://mysite/login.aspx.`

1) Is is possoble?
2) If yes then how, need something from javascript/ jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You can't possibly do anything about what the user does with his clipboard.

You could use ModRewrite to have some fancy URL, but not change what the user gets in clipboard when he copies an ugly URL from addressbar.

Comment: I am not sure but why can't we access the clipboard?

Comment: You would like it if you came across some advertisement on a website and it put a pornsite link to your clipboard? I guess not. That's the reason.

Comment: haha ...No way actually my link is something like http://mysite/admin#ctry=US& lng=en

Comment: but my server code won't find the value after # so I am thinking how to handle if the user has saved my link with # values

Comment: `#` is used to link anchors in page. Why doesn't your URL follow the standard format `file?a=stuff&b=OtherStuff` ?

Comment: many sites that have clipboard access, are using adobe flash. Eg.: github.com

Comment: As there is lot't of ajax call happening and based on that I have to update the URL but if I go with normal querystring then the page will refresh so I have to append in the form of #..

Comment: I don't quite get why you need to change URL because of Ajax calls. If you want to let users bookmark the current state, you can have some fancy `<a>` there, with updated URL, for them to add to bookmarks.

Comment: @Mighty I didn't understand your ans can you please elaborate how can I restricts user to copy or bookmark the link I wanted not the link he is seeing in the address bar

Comment: You can't restrict them from bookmarking what's in their addressbar. **BUT:** I've seen various sites with heavy javascript and ajax, gallery creator and stuff like that. They have a link named "Bookmark Current State" or similar - and users can drag this to their bookmarks menu, or just click it and bookmark the new url. The point is that your JS can change the link's `href` without reloading the page, and when user goes to that URL later, you can restore the state based on data in the link.